# So since Scapy has been renamed to Kamene, how would I import and use base64_bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

So I used to be able to import scapy's `base64_bytes` by using `from scapy.all import base64_bytes`. However, I get this error when I do that:

> PIP package scapy-python3 used to provide scapy3k, which was a fork from scapy implementing python3 compatibility since 2016. This package was included in some of the Linux distros under name of python3-scapy. Starting from scapy version 2.4 (released in March, 2018) mainstream scapy supports python3. To reduce any confusion scapy3k was renamed to kamene.

I tried renaming it to `from kamene.all import base64_bytes`, but still no luck. Is there any other alternative to `base64_bytes` or am I just importing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion between Scapy and kamene. From https://scapy.net

> An independent fork of Scapy was created from v2.2.0 in 2015, aimed at
>   supporting only Python3 (scapy3k). The fork diverged, did not follow
>   evolutions and fixes, and has had its own life without contributions
>   back to Scapy. Unfortunately, it has been packaged as python3-scapy in
>   some distributions, and as scapy-python3 on PyPI leading to confusion
>   amongst users. It should not be the case anymore soon. Scapy supports
>   Python3 in addition to Python2 since 2.4.0. Scapy v2.4.0 should be
>   favored as the official Scapy code base. The fork has been renamed as
>   kamene.

You are using kamene, and old Scapy fork with no support whatsoever.

You probably have installed `scapy-python3` on PyPI. Uninstall it and use `pip3 install scapy`

NOT to use kamene is the best advice I can give you...

Comment: I uninstalled `scapy-python3` and `scapy` was already installed on my system. But, it won't let me import scapy after uninstalling `scapy-python3`.

Comment: Check it is installed on the Python version you use to start your script. Use `python-m pip install scapy` (replace `python` if you use miniconda.....)

Comment: nevermind, I uninstalled then reinstalled scapy and it works perfectly fine now. Thank you!