# Kamene causing python3 segmentation fault

Tags: python-3.x

I have a basic `python3` script for running a ping sweep using `kamene` with two main issues. I'm not sure if they are related so I'll add them both in the same post.

Where in here is the main issue and what have I done wrong?

First issue...
When I import IP and ICMP from `kamena.all` I have an error as below...

`No name 'IP' in module 'kamene.all'pylint(no-name-in-module)`

`No name 'ICMP' in module 'kamene.all'pylint(no-name-in-module)`

Second issue...

When I run the program, I get an `IPv6` error and then a segmentation fault with a warning from OSX to say that python has stopped.

```
python3 pingsweep.py 
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?). This affects only IPv6
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is my script code...

```
from kamene.all import sr1,IP,ICMP

for ip in range(1, 8):
  packet = IP(dst="192.168.0." + str(ip), ttl=20) / ICMP()
  reply = sr1(packet, timeout=2)

  if not (reply is None):
    print(reply.dst)
```

I have installed kamene with...

```
pip3 install kamene
```

Lastly, the crash report from OSX...

```
Process:               Python [13831]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.1 (3.7.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [10827]
Responsible:           Python [13831]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-03-29 15:45:33.205 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.4 (18E226)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        D6F17B07-49F0-ACAE-B5D6-25ABF231369D

Sleep/Wake UUID:       AAE0878E-9596-4A63-BAD9-7146B5F303F5

Time Awake Since Boot: 28000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       16000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000014
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [13831]

VM Regions Near 0x14:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010197b000-000000010197c000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libpcap.A.dylib                 0x00007fff72b9041f pcap_get_selectable_fd + 4
1   _ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so   0x00000001027001d7 ffi_call_unix64 + 79
2   _ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so   0x0000000102700a38 ffi_call + 872
3   _ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so   0x00000001026fb9fb _ctypes_callproc + 891
4   _ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so   0x00000001026f5af0 PyCFuncPtr_call + 1040
5   org.python.python               0x00000001019a08b1 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 433
6   org.python.python               0x0000000101a602f4 call_function + 420
7   org.python.python               0x0000000101a5d4a7 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25351
8   org.python.python               0x00000001019a0ed0 function_code_fastcall + 128
9   org.python.python               0x0000000101a60432 call_function + 738
10  org.python.python               0x0000000101a5d3ec _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25164
11  org.python.python               0x0000000101a60f56 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2422
12  org.python.python               0x00000001019a063b _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 523
13  org.python.python               0x00000001019a190f _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
14  org.python.python               0x00000001019efe91 slot_tp_init + 145
15  org.python.python               0x00000001019eb7e9 type_call + 297
16  org.python.python               0x00000001019a08b1 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 433
17  org.python.python               0x0000000101a602f4 call_function + 420
18  org.python.python               0x0000000101a5d54d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25517
19  org.python.python               0x0000000101a60f56 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2422
20  org.python.python               0x00000001019a0a61 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 257
21  org.python.python               0x0000000101a60432 call_function + 738
22  org.python.python               0x0000000101a5d54d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25517
23  org.python.python               0x0000000101a60f56 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2422
24  org.python.python               0x0000000101a570c4 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
25  org.python.python               0x0000000101a94591 PyRun_FileExFlags + 209
26  org.python.python               0x0000000101a93e0a PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 890
27  org.python.python               0x0000000101ab219b pymain_main + 6827
28  org.python.python               0x0000000101ab26ea _Py_UnixMain + 58
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff73c1b3d5 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007ffeee283290  rcx: 0x00000001019a0373  rdx: 0x00007ffeee283110
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007ffeee283160  rsp: 0x00007ffeee283160
   r8: 0x00007ffeee283110   r9: 0x00000001019a01e8  r10: 0x00007ffeee2830c0  r11: 0x00007fff72b9041b
  r12: 0x00007ffeee2830c0  r13: 0x0000000000000001  r14: 0x0000000102700a60  r15: 0x00007fffa6c14070
  rip: 0x00007fff72b9041f  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000014

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x10197b000 -        0x10197bfff +org.python.python (3.7.1 - 3.7.1) <4B030EC4-815E-34B7-90E7-D0720C31E072> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x10197f000 -        0x101b57fff +org.python.python (3.7.1, [c] 2001-2018 Python Software Foundation. - 3.7.1) <977C0919-F108-3AC9-8796-F42032694A62> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
       0x101f25000 -        0x101f2eff7 +_socket.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <0BA1CC79-DBFC-332D-9DEE-7A81A6654023> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101f7b000 -        0x101f7cfff +_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <E8B35F18-1B5A-3C9E-B1F4-0BE0432459A2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101f80000 -        0x101f84fff +math.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <E18B0A65-B44F-3F1D-96A8-C29A7F794019> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x101f8b000 -        0x101f8dfff +select.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <869F8AE3-73B4-35C4-82CA-3D954FD00F78> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/select.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1021e6000 -        0x1021e8ff7 +_hashlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <13B96FDE-C671-3396-B89D-2ACB4F56A05B> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1021ed000 -        0x10222eff7 +libssl.1.1.dylib (0) <E00648A8-30F5-3638-8774-6EE461AB8CAC> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
       0x10224f000 -        0x10242cc6f +libcrypto.1.1.dylib (0) <4E4019C3-04B3-3DA5-8504-57FF0E7C5600> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
       0x1024ac000 -        0x1024b1ff7 +_blake2.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <5D4A9B1B-FE9F-34EA-BD75-7B3CDDBB7CD0> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1024b6000 -        0x1024c6ff7 +_sha3.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <78945AB7-D4B8-3DCE-8496-EE83FDA05E0D> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1024cc000 -        0x1024ccff7 +_bisect.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <A4FCF31A-2AA6-3EAC-AF46-2F2D10EC1AB1> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1024cf000 -        0x1024d0ff7 +_random.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <CE043712-0C0E-3DA4-AAF2-35654CC67C6D> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1024d4000 -        0x1024d8fff +_struct.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <2379780F-4AB4-394B-B5AB-55A517D6627E> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102521000 -        0x102522ff7 +_posixsubprocess.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <11920A4C-3AD4-3C87-95E5-418D30950610> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102526000 -        0x102527fff +fcntl.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <ADADACC0-C00C-3386-9709-CCB56A7C95E0> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10252b000 -        0x10252eff7 +zlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <CB41B121-E928-3213-92CE-7A26C3F668BF> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102534000 -        0x102539ff7 +array.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <B594CECF-180C-348D-B9DA-11275D232042> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/array.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102654000 -        0x102667fff +_pickle.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <2F30BDA6-A35E-38F0-9096-72DDCA1030B6> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1026f3000 -        0x102703ff7 +_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <78FCD5A2-0B47-331E-A406-2876C1289C15> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102755000 -        0x102756ff7 +_bz2.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <732D55D3-F86E-31E0-95B9-DB921419F7B2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10275a000 -        0x10278aff7 +_lzma.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <91D1CDE2-5956-3869-87A0-29726C9D4C60> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102794000 -        0x102794fff +grp.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <9C889B5E-65A3-339F-8F34-E10FF20A6ED9> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102797000 -        0x10279cff7 +libdnet.dylib (0) <BD67BA1C-F58B-3ABF-89DE-35B09579779F> /usr/local/lib/libdnet.dylib
       0x1027e1000 -        0x1027e3ffb +netifaces.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <0DCF0A83-6515-3E4E-902C-2E0E7FF24E13> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netifaces.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102d04000 -        0x102d48ff7 +_decimal.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <C94BD9E0-CEBA-3930-AB10-15E1FEFAA244> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x102db0000 -        0x102db1ff7 +_queue.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <C457E118-139B-352D-A6F9-DA76389AE74E> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_queue.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x103b9f000 -        0x103c096ef  dyld (655.1.1) <F217F7F8-A795-3109-B77F-B1E2277F3E3B> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff47769000 -     0x7fff47bacfff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1570.16) <F3DFF269-6705-35AD-9F01-66D77DD1B518> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff705a0000 -     0x7fff705a1ffb  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (107) <B5675E8C-2F34-3E0A-B7E8-6F2373589038> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff709df000 -     0x7fff709e0ffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1252.250.1) <72841192-B0C9-36A0-8E55-ED651EADEF08> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff70c14000 -     0x7fff70c21fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib (38.200.3) <62019AC3-20C9-3DDC-9C83-189C1F258073> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff70c22000 -     0x7fff70c75ff7  libc++.1.dylib (400.9.4) <446DAE5E-4E97-3E4B-B2A3-AC0A74C0E453> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff70c76000 -     0x7fff70c8bff7  libc++abi.dylib (400.17) <A2D1FDAD-E10F-3E53-958F-CB6BC8485767> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff71898000 -     0x7fff71af8ff3  libicucore.A.dylib (62123.0.1) <3936C798-1978-3C6C-9050-3BBD57CDA53E> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff723d9000 -     0x7fff72b5efdf  libobjc.A.dylib (756.2) <4F86FC7C-496B-3E68-8A74-1EA2BA22FBCC> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff72b77000 -     0x7fff72bacfff  libpcap.A.dylib (79.250.1) <FA490ABF-6C15-336A-818F-0C14A8C090DB> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
    0x7fff732af000 -     0x7fff732c1ff7  libz.1.dylib (70.200.4) <FDF169F3-F992-3E8E-B3F7-D4134FEBAE41> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff73a9e000 -     0x7fff73aa2ff3  libcache.dylib (81) <9A8C27B0-49C9-337F-8BE2-37171ED2D8EE> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff73aa3000 -     0x7fff73aadff3  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60118.250.2) <17C4F395-9FF0-331F-8167-5E85AA3588E9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff73aae000 -     0x7fff73ab5ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (63.4) <8CB2B2B6-2C55-3733-9842-0E037AE3F46A> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff73ab6000 -     0x7fff73abfff7  libcopyfile.dylib (146.250.1) <24905E41-9E2F-3DD1-A255-5A17F9FCDAD7> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff73ac0000 -     0x7fff73b44fc7  libcorecrypto.dylib (602.250.23) <3A6CBD41-AFFE-3E06-B1EC-3E95BC79BAC5> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff73bcb000 -     0x7fff73c04ff7  libdispatch.dylib (1008.250.7) <50235FCE-B399-3319-90DC-88F530D4FC5C> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff73c05000 -     0x7fff73c31ff7  libdyld.dylib (655.1.1) <54C6B494-4A3D-3EEC-B083-636A76AAD649> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff73c32000 -     0x7fff73c32ffb  libkeymgr.dylib (30) <BEA04E04-FCF1-3A70-810F-08D0FF54CA36> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff73c40000 -     0x7fff73c40ff7  liblaunch.dylib (1336.251.2) <30E6424E-4640-3DBA-9B64-D5F725263C6E> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff73c41000 -     0x7fff73c46fff  libmacho.dylib (927.0.2) <D8515A20-ED7B-3B13-9ADA-4BD7E19E38C4> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff73c47000 -     0x7fff73c49ffb  libquarantine.dylib (86.220.1) <8A9BF971-DB7D-311A-B131-6C5025E82F8F> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff73c4a000 -     0x7fff73c4bff7  libremovefile.dylib (45.200.2) <950036B7-B91E-3B5D-853C-8C551E5B6A32> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff73c4c000 -     0x7fff73c63ff3  libsystem_asl.dylib (356.200.4) <16F632AD-FADA-3DE9-85E8-EBC7D619A1DA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff73c64000 -     0x7fff73c64ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (73) <0CD6861B-EC5F-3345-9C24-B21EEB85E44F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff73c65000 -     0x7fff73cecfff  libsystem_c.dylib (1272.250.1) <F3AA9047-EEDD-3D80-8CC1-023FB312EC8B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff73ced000 -     0x7fff73cf0ffb  libsystem_configuration.dylib (963.250.1) <02C7A973-014A-31D7-B7D2-247D384CB0D2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff73cf1000 -     0x7fff73cf4ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (66) <4CF1C89B-FA6C-3DF3-B1F8-79F549849534> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff73cf5000 -     0x7fff73cfbfff  libsystem_darwin.dylib (1272.250.1) <6983A268-20F4-3F98-A3F5-D63848933B02> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
    0x7fff73cfc000 -     0x7fff73d02ff7  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (878.250.4) <9FC5724C-DD03-3E14-A6E1-2DD009D79E0A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff73d03000 -     0x7fff73d4effb  libsystem_info.dylib (517.200.9) <F617D3CF-5A4A-36D0-8CBB-4A7C7CDB67AF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff73d4f000 -     0x7fff73d77ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (4903.251.3) <84EF0290-6CB5-36E5-A273-692A7E437B36> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff73d78000 -     0x7fff73dc3ff7  libsystem_m.dylib (3158.200.7) <33105665-CCC3-36D5-82C9-9B21730CB3DF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff73dc4000 -     0x7fff73de8fff  libsystem_malloc.dylib (166.251.2) <90DA09E3-1276-3FCF-8F5F-C9AA61AB9B6D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff73de9000 -     0x7fff73df3ff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (767.250.2) <4575D797-B793-3D18-9E93-8696CF0B133B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff73df4000 -     0x7fff73dfbfff  libsystem_notify.dylib (172.200.21) <679E9132-1A46-326E-9A11-D3FF9C86041C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff73dfc000 -     0x7fff73e05fef  libsystem_platform.dylib (177.250.1) <3CC59141-5365-3848-94C3-D65E6FCA1E74> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff73e06000 -     0x7fff73e10ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (330.250.2) <4344198A-A1A3-3C52-97B4-F168D56E9789> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff73e11000 -     0x7fff73e14ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (851.250.12) <66E91015-F62A-3365-BB81-AA88707E8F12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff73e15000 -     0x7fff73e17ff3  libsystem_secinit.dylib (30.220.1) <F054DCB0-68CE-35E7-8B8C-D648C42124EC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff73e18000 -     0x7fff73e1fff3  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (820.257.1) <C8517F35-E9DA-3649-B07D-2B38349C6730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff73e20000 -     0x7fff73e35fff  libsystem_trace.dylib (906.250.5) <AE77ACC7-488F-3AE1-BB0C-1ACFC7E1CE77> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff73e37000 -     0x7fff73e3cffb  libunwind.dylib (35.4) <8F0BC197-B97C-3DDC-92B0-6A7D3CB72FD8> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff73e3d000 -     0x7fff73e6cff7  libxpc.dylib (1336.251.2) <49138829-09C8-355C-B558-97E070B84EC5> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 15008
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=246.6M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=246.6M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=65.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=65.1M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            48.3M       22 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            384K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                          4K        1 
Stack                             16.0M        1 
VM_ALLOCATE                          4K        1 
__DATA                            5684K       74 
__LINKEDIT                       223.1M       29 
__TEXT                            23.5M       71 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
shared memory                       12K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            317.5M      210 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   317.1M      210 

Model: MacBookPro11,1, BootROM 151.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.16f68
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisItem, Intel Iris, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.2 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.8)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.11f4, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.2
```

Comment: You should probably have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54578802/5459467 Kamene is so old it has no builtin OSX support

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issues with Scapy, so I'll assume that's only related to Kamene (I have edited your question to reflect that).

You can either try using the "real" Scapy (https://github.com/secdev/scapy), or report this issue to the Kamene project.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to permissions issue with mac. The python program is not able to get write to the packet on to network. I had a similar issue and using sudo resolved the issue.

Comment: You didi not solve anything with this answer. Write a comment instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).